# Bad shading on icosphere set to smooth

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, normals, shadows

I used an icosphere to model a part of a building, I have autosmooth enabled with custom sharp edges but I can't fix the bad shading. In Eevee it looks perfect, but in cycles I get weird shading that follows the edges of the tris instead of working like it should. Is it a problem from lighting (I'm using an hdri), from normals or should I just avoid using triangles and use quads? I already merged by distance so there aren't any overlapping vertices and all the normals are facing the right directions.
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe the "terminator effect"? In that case, try to scale up the size of the light (the new name for light size in 2.8 is "angle"). But it should be fixed in next Blender versions...

Comment: But i'm using only an hdri image, there aren't any normal lights like lamps in the scene.. does that apply to hdri as well?

Comment: I couldn't tell, maybe pack the image and share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Maybe try with lamps and without hdri for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found to render the mesh with the hdri while keeping it low poly without getting the terminator artifacts was rendering it in Unreal Engine 4.

Answer (score 0):

Terminator effect, only way to make it work is using more geometry.

Comment: Do i just need more geometry or different type like quads instead of tris (like using a uv sphere instead of ichosphere for example)? Because i tried increasing geometry by subdiving the tris with smootheness on but the same problem was still there.